# Why is NaiveBayes Model having fitting error?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

# Step 1: Load the dataset
df = pd.read_csv('articles1.csv')

# Step 2: Split the dataset into training and testing sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['content'], df['author'], test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Step 3: Create a Pipeline
# This pipeline will first convert the text data into TF-IDF vectorized form,
# then apply a Naive Bayes classifier to perform the author identification.
model = make_pipeline(TfidfVectorizer(), MultinomialNB())

# Step 4: Train the model
model=model.fit(X_train, y_train)

The error is 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-00ad871f55dc> in <module>
     18 
     19 # Step 4: Train the model
---> 20 model=model.fit(X_train, y_train)


~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    344             if self._final_estimator != 'passthrough':
    345                 fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
--> 346                 self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
    347 
    348         return self

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    610         self : object
    611         """
--> 612         X, y = self._check_X_y(X, y)
    613         _, n_features = X.shape
    614         self.n_features_ = n_features



ValueError: Input contains NaN
```

Please check for me and help me crosscheck what might be wrong with the code. The work is to predict authors. Kindly help me go through it and analyse it better. Thank you all. It is  the use of binomial naive bayes algorithm for machine analysis. The last part is also complaining of the input containing Not A Number. The source of dat without number can not be ascertained as yet.

Comment: Your data has NaNs, you should fix that, there is nothing wrong  with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle missing values (NaNs)
Quickly you can do something like below:
Option1

```
# Example imputing missing values with mean
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='mean')
X_train_imputed = imputer.fit_transform(X_train)
```

Option2:
If missing values are limited,

```
# Example dropping rows with missing values
X_train.dropna(inplace=True)
y_train = y_train[X_train.index]
```